Cardinality issue with graph execution in TensorFlow
I was using a TFRecord and couldn't get past a cardinality issue to get it to work with graph execution.  I switched back to a regular dataset loading method and now I have another cardinality issue.
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/trainers/data_adapters/tf_dataset_adapter.py", line 57, in num_batches
    cardinality = int(self._dataset.cardinality())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'SymbolicTensor'

I have done all of the suggested methods for fixing it, and have correctly set the cardinality of the dataset.  I have verified my cardinality in many ways.  In eager execution I can simply print
print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy())

But in graph execution the changed code is much harder to understand
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.assert_cardinality(self.num_batches))
cardinality = self.get_cardinality(dataset)
print(cardinality)
print(cardinality == tf.data.experimental.INFINITE_CARDINALITY)
print(cardinality == tf.data.experimental.UNKNOWN_CARDINALITY)

Which gives Tensor("PartitionedCall:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) and False for both beforehand. (the cardinality was set to '3')
After setting the cardinality, it gives Tensor("PartitionedCall_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) and False for both.  If I remove the @tf_function from my get_cardinality method (I read using a return object makes it possible to get it in graph execution which is why I'm using a function), the output becomes the same but of type DatasetCardinality: Tensor("DatasetCardinality_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64).
I have dug, for hundreds of hours, trying to fix my code over months now and have read all of the documentation down to the source code.
This is what is getting called and wants the cardinality:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v3.3.3/keras/src/trainers/data_adapters/tf_dataset_adapter.py
I think there needs to be some page I've missed which goes over why graph execution is doing what it's doing and why it wants cardinality etc.  The wierdest part is over the past couple months this exact code has worked and I've gone back to my github and copied various portions of it.  So I think the issue could lie in tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution or something which changes how graph execution is set up.  I also have tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False) and run_eagerly=False in my compile().
